# Find most common shared vertices in OrientDB

Tags: orientdb, graph-databases, recommendation-engine

I'm currently evaluating OrientDB (2.1.16) as a possible solution to building a similarity recommender. To that end, I'd love some help writing an initial query that accomplishes the following:

```
Vertex:Maker -(Edge:Produced)-> Vertex:Item -(Edge:TaggedBy)-> Vertex:Tag
```

1. I'd like to select a particular Item `(V1)` and get a list back of other Items `(Vn)` ordered by the number of Tags shared in common with `V1`;
2. By extension, I'd like to take a selected Maker `(V2)` and traverse through Items to get an ordered list of Makers (and the traversed Items, if possible) who share Tags.

There isn't an awful lot of detailed documentation on the application of intersect in this way. No unusual constraints in particular. There would be thousands of Items and Makers and probably 10x that many Tags.

Comment: Hi, it could be useful a JS function?

Comment: As a server-side script? That looks like it might work. I'd hoped for a direct query, but I'll look into this as an option. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: is it a constraint to use 2.1.16? Latest stable (2.2.3) includes the new MATCH statement, that makes this kind of tasks much easier.

Comment: Nope... not a constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with this little graph example

[image]

I used this query

```
select item.name, count(tag)from (
    select from (
        MATCH {
            CLASS:Item, AS:item, WHERE: (name<>'v1')
        } 
        .out("TaggedBy"){AS:tag}
        return item, tag
    ) where tag in (
        select expand(tag) from (
            MATCH {
                CLASS:Item, AS:item, WHERE: (name='v1')
            }.out("TaggedBy"){AS:tag}
            return tag
        )
     )
) group by item order by count desc
```

and I got this result

[image: enter code here]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I dropped this approach after coming to conclusion that my use case was better suited to a standard relational database since I'm not traversing relationships.